# Использование google fonts в android studio

Tags: мобильные-приложения

В общем дело такое, пишу небольшое приложение андроид. в прошлый раз пробовал различные шрифты и проблем не возникало, но сейчас, стоит мне добавить любой другой шрифт - на телефоне отображается лишь стандартный, я перечитал пару статей и сделал всё в точности то, что там сказано и в превью показывает используемые шрифты, но на телефоне они не отображаются, попробовал ещё на двух - эффект тот же.

Comment: А где же Ваш код?

Comment: Не думаю, что вам это поможет, но:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans_thin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в папке **main** создайте папку assets

в папке **assets** создайте папку **fonts**

в папку **fonts** скопируйте файл шрифтов **white_christmas.ttf**

файл со шрифтом подставьте свой

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package ru.site.a1

import android.graphics.Typeface
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  //установка шрифта
  textView1.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/white_christmas.ttf")
 }

}
```

Comment: Сделал, но стал выдавать NullPointerException java
`textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/work_sans_thin.ttf"));`

Comment: Какой язык программирования используете?

Comment: java, я исправил эту ошибку, сам ошибся, всё работает, но шрифты остаются стандартными, хоть и делал так, как сказано

Comment: Нет, всё же помогло, спасибо. благодарю)

Comment: android:fontFamily — тип шрифта. Если помогло, то отметье ответ

Comment: типы шрифтов: monospace, serif, serif-monospace, sans-serif, sans-serif-condensed, sans-serif-smallcaps, sans-serif-light, casual, cursive

Comment: android:fontFamily="cursive"

Comment: Понял, ещё раз огромное спасибо)